# Find the missing time data between two dataframe time column using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframe with time column:

`df1`

```
EST_TIME
2017-01-01 00:00:00
2017-01-01 00:01:00
2017-01-01 00:02:00
2017-01-01 00:03:00
2017-01-01 00:04:00
2017-01-01 00:05:00
2017-01-01 00:06:00
2017-01-01 00:07:00
...
```

`df2`

```
EST_TIME_2
2017-01-01 00:00:00
2017-01-01 00:01:00
2017-01-01 00:02:00
2017-01-01 00:04:00
2017-01-01 00:05:00
2017-01-01 00:07:00
...
```

I want to compare and find the missing values between the two `dataframe`

Eg: the missing value in the above `dataset` is the following:

```
2017-01-01 00:03:00
2017-01-01 00:06:00
```

I want a similar output.

**What did I do?**

I wrote this code:

```
[df[EST_TIME] != df2[EST_TIME]]
```

My assumption is that it would return the value that does not match, but it did not work.

**Output would look like:**

```
2017-01-01 00:03:00
2017-01-01 00:06:00
```

Comment: can you try `m = df1[EST_TIME].isin(df2[EST_TIME])` then do `df1[m]` or `df1[~m]`

Comment: It looks like loaded all values, I do not see any differences. I just want values that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"EST_TIME":["2017-01-01 00:00:00",
"2017-01-01 00:01:00",
"2017-01-01 00:02:00",
"2017-01-01 00:03:00",
"2017-01-01 00:04:00",
"2017-01-01 00:05:00",
"2017-01-01 00:06:00",
"2017-01-01 00:07:00"]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"EST_TIME_2":["2017-01-01 00:00:00",
"2017-01-01 00:01:00",
"2017-01-01 00:02:00",
"2017-01-01 00:04:00",
"2017-01-01 00:05:00",
"2017-01-01 00:07:00"]})

df1["EST_TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["EST_TIME"])
df2["EST_TIME_2"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["EST_TIME_2"])
output = df1[~(df1["EST_TIME"].isin(df2["EST_TIME_2"]))]
```

output

```
             EST_TIME
3 2017-01-01 00:03:00
6 2017-01-01 00:06:00
```

Comment: It does not give me the desired output. ITs almost the same output as above comments.

Comment: what are the data type of the columns?string or datetime.it works for me for both types

Comment: `datetime` is the type

Comment: it works fine.check the updated answer and check with your df1 and df2

Answer (score 0):

The following will check for missing datetime (minute frequency) in both dataframes.
Setup

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'est_time': [
        '2017-01-01 00:00:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:01:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:02:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:03:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:04:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:05:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:06:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:07:00'
    ]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'est_time': [
        '2017-01-01 00:00:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:01:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:02:00',
        # '2017-01-01 00:03:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:04:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:05:00',
        # '2017-01-01 00:06:00',
        '2017-01-01 00:07:00'
    ]
})
df1.est_time = pd.to_datetime(df1.est_time)
df2.est_time = pd.to_datetime(df2.est_time)
```

Now we define a time range from the minimum time point to the maximum time point (of both df1 and df2)

```py
r = pd.date_range(min(df1.est_time.min(), df2.est_time.min()), max(df1.est_time.max(), df2.est_time.max()), freq= 'min')
ds_range = pd.DataFrame({'est_time': r})
```

Finally, we just need to check for missing values

```py
missing_df1 = ds_range[~ds_range.est_time.isin(df1.est_time)]
missing_df2 = ds_range[~ds_range.est_time.isin(df2.est_time)]
missing = pd.concat([missing_df1, missing_df2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```

This gives:

```py
est_time
0 2017-01-01 00:03:00
1 2017-01-01 00:06:00
```

The key idea is to define your desired time range with a specific frequency. You can otherwise create 2 separate ranges corresponding to df1 and df2.